# rviz disagrees with gazebo visuals?

Tags: gazebo, rviz, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been modelling a new robot in URDF, and I tweaked the URDF using the `urdf_tutorial` package's `xacrodisplay.launch` to verify the model.  I recently started using meshes to get a better visual look, and I have run into an issue where the visuals between the rviz from xacrodisplay and gazebo are different.  If I line up the mesh checking by rotations / translations in rviz, and then switch to gazebo, it is all jacked up.  See the images below for comparison (this is just after I tried to "fix" it in gazebo).  I'm trying to figure out why the representations would be different when working from the same URDF file (available for inspection [here](https://gist.github.com/f0da3bc34c7418a45e2e)).

[image: Rviz]

[image: Gazebo]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48782/rviz-disagrees-with-gazebo-visuals?/) by [jamuraa](https://answers.ros.org/users/534/jamuraa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 218 on 2012-11-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This bug still seems to exist in Fuerte as of Jan 2013.

See these posts:  
https://kforge.ros.org/gazebo/trac/ticket/59 
http://answers.ros.org/question/32849/visual-and-collision-geometry-misaligned-in-gazebo-10/

To get around this, keep all your visual rotations zero.  
If the visual mesh needs to be rotated with respect to the joint reference frame, either modify the mesh to match your link frame (which is the best idea to keep your URDF simple), or add an extra dummy joint+link with the required rotation.

---

Originally posted by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) with karma: 1103 on 2013-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jamuraa](https://answers.ros.org/users/534/jamuraa/) on 2013-01-16**:
I don't think the other one is related, because if I try the URDF that he has there, it is as expected.  That ticket from Gazebo is enlightening though.  I have been working on groovy compiling and installed, which uses Gazebo 1.2, which I'm hoping this problem is solved in.

**Comment by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on 2013-01-17**:
Yes, your original question should mention which versions you are using.